# AngularJS: Two-Way Data Binding with Number Inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use angular for data-binding `input type="number"` elements, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the binding working.  For example, when I update any of the values, I expect the value binded to it to also update.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/kiqivule/3/edit

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what you really expect to see? when you increase bike do you want to increse tires as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.  Something like this: http://jsbin.com/kiqivule/14/edit

Comment: Ur solution: http://jsbin.com/guxom/1/

Comment: @BijayRai, no, it's not fully two-way.  I'm currently looking at ``$scope.$watchGroup()``.  See http://jsbin.com/kiqivule/22/edit - but it's not working...?

Comment: You're using a version of angular which doesn't support `$watchGroup`. [Check my update](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24646404/127497).

Answer (score 0):

Use `$watch`:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tires = $scope.bikes * 2;

    $scope.$watch('bikes', function(){
        $scope.tires = $scope.bikes * 2;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- You should be defining your model in a "model" type property - see here for details: http://zcourts.com/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/
- You need to "watch" for changes to the "bikes" property in order to update the "tires" property.

Here's an updated JSBin showing how to do it: http://jsbin.com/kiqivule/15/edit?html,js,output

### Update

Firstly, [$watchGroup only came in at v1.3.0-beta.6](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/21f93163384f36fc4ae0934387339380e3dc3e9c) - in [your script](http://jsbin.com/kiqivule/22/edit) you're using v1.2.10.

Secondly, all the jsbins that are referenced here are showing that the tires property is being updated when the bikes property is being updated. [Here's another jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kiqivule/26/edit) which show this a bit more clearly.

So I'm still not sure what you're chasing here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - the code is just demonstrating the principle of using "watch" to keep your values updated. If you need "bikes" to update after you update "tires", you can just add in a second watch.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not 2-way binding.

`app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {`

`$scope.tires = $scope.bikes * 2;`

`});`

The above will only set the tires value when the controller is invoked and not when the value of bikes changes. This can be achieved by adding a watch on Bikes, which will tires values when ever bikes value changes

`app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {`

`$scope.$watch('bikes', function(){`

```
` $scope.tires = $scope.bikes * 2;`
```

`})`

`});`

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1- `ng-change:

```
<input type="number" 
    ng-change="tires = bikes * 2"
    min="0" ng-model="bikes" placeholder="Bikes" id = "bikes"/>
```

Or....

2- `$watch`:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('bikes', function(newValue, oldValue) {
      if(newValue === oldValue) {
          return; // Angular calls watch at initialization with no change
      }
      $scope.tires = $scope.bikes * 2;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In html,

Use ng-change:

```
<input type="number" min="0" ng-model="bikes" placeholder="Bikes"
  ng-change="Calc()" id = "bikes"/>
```

In JS,

```
$scope.Calc = function(){
   $scope.tires = $scope.bikes * 2;
};
```

Hope it helps.........