# Emberjs: Two-Way Data-binding between Number Inputs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am looking at data binding in Ember, and I want to bind two `input type="number"` elements so that changing either of the elements will update the other element.  [Here is the JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/cazeriri/1/edit).

What I would like to have is the following:

```
Biker = DS.Model.extend(
    bikes: (->
        @get("tires") / 2
    ).property("tires")
    tires: (->
        @get("bikes") * 2
    ).property("bikes")
)
```

But that will result in the following stack overflow:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded ember.js:1
>   Ember.assert ember.js:1 get ember.js:2167
>   Ember.Observable.Ember.Mixin.create.get ember.js:12425 (anonymous
>   function) biker.js:32 ComputedPropertyPrototype.get ember.js:4951 get
>   ember.js:2176 Ember.Observable.Ember.Mixin.create.get ember.js:12425
>   (anonymous function) biker.js:29 ComputedPropertyPrototype.get

What is the best way to achieve 2-way **absolute** data-binding with `input` elements?

Note: [I asked something similar, but about angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646284/angularjs-two-way-data-binding-with-number-inputs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing circular code, have just one of the properties watch the other. [Ember's computed properties](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/) allow you to define setter and getter functions for this exact purpose:

```
App.Biker = DS.Model.extend({
  bikes: DS.attr('number'),
  tires: function(key, value) {
    // Setter
    // Says: if we did this.set('tires', something);
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      var bikes = value != 0 ? value / 2 : 0; // Incase zero bikes
      this.set('bikes',  bikes);
    }

    // Getter
    return this.get('bikes') * 2;
  }.property('bikes')
})
```

Comment: Well you're not calling the model, you're just setting the model as a random array of objects. Instead, set up [Ember.FIXTURES](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/) and, in your model method return `this.store.find('biker')`. Regardless, I don't think that will change the properties shown in the template because the `valueBinding` on each `input` is a bound to a property on the controller's `content` property, not the route's model. You're better off setting the computed properties on the controller and using DS.attr('number') for both `bikes` and `tires` in the model.

Comment: [Here is a working JS Bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bupumase/1). Part of what I said in my above comment is unnecessary but the answer remains the same.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to explain any parts of the JS Bin.